# 'Split' - text file to list - IndexError (Using Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split, text-files

This is my code:

```
with open("userDetails.txt", "r") as userDetailsFile:
        for line in userDetailsFile:
            if bestUsername in line:
                for line in userDetailsFile:
                    bestAchiever = line.split('|')
                    user = bestAchiever[0]
                    firstName = bestAchiever[1]
                    surname = bestAchiever[2]
                    age = bestAchiever[3]
                    yearGroup = bestAchiever[4]
```

This is what the `userDetailsFile` looks like:

```
john14|john|doe|14|11
```

I'm getting the error:

```
firstName = bestAchiever[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea why this is? I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You have a line with no `|` character in it (maybe it's an empty line).

Comment: @CristiFati But `john14|john|doe|14|11` is eactly what the file looks like? I'm kind of confused...

Comment: Doesn't that line have an *EOLN* (`\n`, *0X0A*) at the end?

Comment: @CristiFati What does that even mean??

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: remove your 3rd and 4th line and then correct the indentation, see what you get

Comment: @mamun I'm still getting the same error: `firstName = bestAchiever[1]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. 
For those who are having the same problem, this is what I did wrong:

```
lineWithoutNewLine = line.rstrip('\n')
bestAchiever = lineWithoutNewLine.split('|') 
user = bestAchiever[0]
firstName = bestAchiever[1]
surname = bestAchiever[2]
age = bestAchiever[3]
yearGroup = bestAchiever[4]
```

I had to add in the `line.rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 1):

What is `bestAchiever` at that point?  Not what you *think* it is, what the *computer* thinks it is?  That should be your first debugging step.

The run-time error suggests that the variable has a length less than 2.

Note that you have a serious logic error:

```
    for line in userDetailsFile:
        if bestUsername in line:
            for line in userDetailsFile:
```

Your first and third loops are fighting for control of `line`.  This is *not* going to end well for you.

Comment: But I've used this same method in other parts of my program as I've seen it suggested by other stack overflow users. It's the same approach used?

Comment: I think not -- please provide references.  The code you've posted here suggests that you've made some changes to the original intent of such an answer.

Comment: I'm so confused. What way is it supposed to look?

Comment: We don't know: you haven't described the problem you're solving; you haven't supplied the requested MCVE (including *actual* input file), or the references to earlier answers that you mentioned.  We're a good community, but we don't read your mind and then do your homework -- that's a little beyond our capabilities.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you are trying to do, but be careful with the inner loop on userDetailsFile. You are using the same file descriptor to keep iterating.

If your file is not big, you probably want to do a `userDetailsFile.readlines()` to get the whole content into a list, and do the loops on this list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your problem details but here is what I think you would like to have:

```
best_user = 'john14'
with open('userdetailsfile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if best_user in line:
            words = line.split('|')
            f_name, s_name, age, yeargroup = words
```

Let me know if it works.